# Reimport modules: Reload not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, reload

I am a Matlab user and new to Python. I want to call the simplest python function from an external file. I edit the function, but my Canopy interpreter (IPython) does not recognize the new version and keeps calling the old file!

Say this function saved as mymodule.py:

```
def oper(x):
  print(x)
```

The main file is:

```
del mymodule.pyc 
import mymodule
import imp
imp.reload(mymodule)

oper(5)
```

Run this once. Change print(x) to print(x+1). It keeps executing print(x).
If I define the function oper(x) in the main file, or if I close Canopy and reopen it, or if I reset the Canopy kernel via GUI Run>Reset Kernel,  it's all right (but I cannot program these).

I also tried reload(mymodule) and %reset, which do not solve the problem. Ideally, I want a Python command in the main file that would completely reset the workspace (kernels, namespctes etc). I am using Canopy 1.7.4.3348,  which includes Python 2.7.11 and IPython 4.0.0.9.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import like this and use like

```
from mymodule import oper
oper(5)
```

or

```
import mymodule
mymodule.oper(5)
```

Also, in the same directory of mymodule, create an empty `__init__.py` file there. That will let python know that it is a module.

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't answer OP's question.  He wants to know how to re-import a module in an interactive session to use an updated version of the function from his module.

Comment: I did both steps you mentioned. It does not solve the problem!